# Use of javascript variable in php if statement

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement

In my code i have done an ajax script with json and saved the variable you can see below. After that i'm trying to use the variable in my **if statement**, which is coded in php. Is it possible to do that?

```
          //Script variables 
                var $trstatus_1; //value = GROUP_3, GROUP_2, GROUP_1 or UNDEF
           </script>

           <?php

                //Status 

                $id; //php variable

                echo "<div id='images'>";
                if($trstatus_1 == "GROUP_3"){
                    echo    "<a id='".$id1."' class='tooltip1' href='#'><img src='ball_red_glossy.png' alt='' width='70' height='50'  style='position: relative; left: 0px;' /><span>RED</span></a>";
                }   
                else if($trstatus_1== "GROUP_2"){
                    echo    "<a id='".$id1."' class='tooltip1' href='#'><img src='ball_orange_glossy.png' alt='' width='70' height='50'  style='position: relative; left: 0px;' /><span>ORANGE</span></a>";
                }
                else if($trstatus_1 == "GROUP_1"){
                    echo    "<a id='".$id1."' class='tooltip1' href='#'><img  src='ball_yellow_glossy.png' alt='' width='70' height='50'  style='position: relative; left: 0px;' /><span>YELLOW</span></a>";
                }
                else if($trstatus_1 == "UNDEF"){
                    echo    "<a id='".$id1."' class='tooltip1' href='#'><img  src='ball_blue_glossy.png' alt='' width='70' height='50'  style='position: relative; left: 0px;' /><span>BLUE</span></a>";
                }
                echo "</div>";
           ?>
```

So yes, the only question is if it is possible to use $trstatus_1 in my IF STATEMENT. and how :)

BR

Alex

UPDATE

```
<script>

setInterval("yourAjaxCall()",10000);
                function yourAjaxCall() 

                {

                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",   
                        url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
                        data:  {vtrstatus: $V_TR_STATUS},                       //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                        dataType: 'json',                //data format
                        success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
                        {   


                            var trstatus = data[0].group_class;
                            trstatus_1 = trstatus;
                            var trstatus_1;
                            //alert(trstatus_1);

                        } 

                    });
                  };
 </script>
<script>
                //Script variables

                var trstatus_1;
                var color;

                if( $trstatus_1 == 'GROUP_1' ){
                    color = 'red';
                }else if ( $trstatus_1 == 'GROUP_2' ){
                    color = 'orange';
                }else if ( $trstatus_1 == 'GROUP_3' ){
                    color = 'yellow';
                }else if ( $trstatus_1 == 'UNDEF' ){
                    color = 'blue';
                }

                var el = "<a class='tooltip1' href='#'><img src='ball_" + color + "_glossy.png' alt='' width='70' height='50'  style='position: relative; left: 0px;' /><span>" color.toUpperCase() "</span></a>";


                $('#images').append(el);

      </script>
                <div id="images">
                </div>
```

Is this correct?

BR

Comment: No, it is not. PHP is server side and Javascript is client side. Javascript will run after PHP finished. You can only transfer a value from Javascript to PHP by requesting a new PHP from the server

Comment: @alex java !== javascript

Comment: @devnull69 [There is no "Javascript"](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix), and the ECMAScript implementation  is client-side, and PHP is server-side *here*.

Comment: indeed, granted. For matters of completeness: There are ECMAScript implementations that are server side. But in this example I assumed you are using a client side implementation commonly called "Javascript" :-)

Comment: it would appear that the your JavaScript variable is invalid as it has a '$' at the beginning.. I'm not 100% sure that that's not right but I wouldn't do it myself...

Comment: @billy the $ is a normal character in js, so you can use it in variables as you see fit. For example, it is very normal to create a variable named $ to store the jQuery object if you are working with jQuery

Comment: Ah, fair enough, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

What are you trying to do? You could try adding those buttons with javascript instead of PHP, or you can reload the page, posting the variable to use in PHP

JavaScript solution:

```
var trstatus_1;
var color;

if( trstatus_1 == 'GROUP_1' ){
    color = 'blue';
}elseif ( trstatus_1 == 'GROUP_2' ){
    color = 'red';
}elseif ( trstatus_1 == 'GROUP_3' ){
    color = 'green';
}elseif ( trstatus_1 == 'UNDEF' ){
    color = 'yellow';
}//sorry for being too lazy to do the colours right

var el = "<a id='SeeNotesBelow' class='tooltip1' href='#'><img src='ball_" + color + "_glossy.png' alt='' width='70' height='50'  style='position: relative; left: 0px;' /><span>" + color.toUpperCase() + "</span></a>"

//assuming jQuery
$('#images').append(el);
//also assuming #images already exists
```

Note: if you need the ID to be generated in PHP, create the element, then modify it, like so:

```
//again, assuming jQuery
$('#images .tooltip1 img').src = 'ball_' + color + '_glossy.png';
$('#images .tooltip1 span').innerHTML = color.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: These images i'm trying to write out are going to be used in an animation later and need to get a working if statement. The page is not going to reload. Got an interval that is looping ajax to fetch new data. Tried to do all as javascript, but failed.

Comment: I would suggest doing it as JavaScript.. Give me a minute.

Comment: @AlexGoransson Any luck with my answer now?

Comment: Well, trying to figure out how it works. Not getting it work this far. I don't need an ID right? Is it supposed to be enough with$('#images').append(el); ? The pictures don't show up atm. I have a div which id is "images". They are supposed to show up there right?

Comment: Yes, they should. Are you running jQuery? Is there any HTML appearing in the 'images' div?

Comment: I wrote this one out $('#images').append(el); in script. Do I need the other $('#images .tooltip1 img').src = 'ball_' + color + '_glossy.png';
$('#images .tooltip1 span').innerHTML = color.toUpperCase(); when i dont have an id for my <a>?

Comment: I think the problem is when i try to output the picture in this part: $('#images').append(el);  -  I'll update my question and you can see how it looks like. Thanks @BillyMathews

Answer (score 0):

Not it's not possible as Javascript runs on the client and PHP on the server. But you could post your javascript variable to that PHP page and get the variable value to be used in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code executes in Server side. 
Javascript code executes in Client Side.

You can populate Javascript variable from PHP as server side script is executed first but the reverse is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can just reduce the php part to the following line

```
echo    "<a id='".$id1."' class='tooltip1' href='#'><img src='#' alt='' width='70' height='50'  style='position: relative; left: 0px;' /><span></span></a>";
```

and then move the if on the javascript side and modify the markup based on the value of trstatus.

Comment: Tried to reduce php as you say and do the if in script. But somehow the php dont listen to the if statements and all four imgs are wrote out.

Comment: What I meant was: if you have your status value on the js, you can just print out the container in php and then move the logic to the js. You will have a page with the html structure and will only need to fill it with the right values for the image src and the description in the span element. Are you using any js framework?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
var $trstatus_1; //value = GROUP_3, GROUP_2, GROUP_1 or UNDEF

   sessionSave('status',$trstatus_1);
    function sessionSave(field,value)
    {
    val = $(value).val();
    $.post("sessionpage.php", { name: field, value:val } );
    }

  </script>    
//new page in php
    sessionpage.php
    <?php session_start();
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $value=$_REQUEST['value'];
    $_SESSION[$name]=nl2br($value);
     ?>
 <?php
                // new variable
                $trstatus_1=$_SESSION['status'];//value = GROUP_3, GROUP_2, GROUP_1 or UNDEF
                //Status 

                $id; //php variable

                echo "<div id='images'>";
                if($trstatus_1 == "GROUP_3"){
                    echo    "<a id='".$id1."' class='tooltip1' href='#'><img src='ball_red_glossy.png' alt='' width='70' height='50'  style='position: relative; left: 0px;' /><span>RED</span></a>";
                }   
                else if($trstatus_1== "GROUP_2"){
                    echo    "<a id='".$id1."' class='tooltip1' href='#'><img src='ball_orange_glossy.png' alt='' width='70' height='50'  style='position: relative; left: 0px;' /><span>ORANGE</span></a>";
                }
                else if($trstatus_1 == "GROUP_1"){
                    echo    "<a id='".$id1."' class='tooltip1' href='#'><img  src='ball_yellow_glossy.png' alt='' width='70' height='50'  style='position: relative; left: 0px;' /><span>YELLOW</span></a>";
                }
                else if($trstatus_1 == "UNDEF"){
                    echo    "<a id='".$id1."' class='tooltip1' href='#'><img  src='ball_blue_glossy.png' alt='' width='70' height='50'  style='position: relative; left: 0px;' /><span>BLUE</span></a>";
                }
                echo "</div>";
           ?>
```

Comment: @Alex Goransson Its possible by this step working fine we tested $trstatus_1 store in session variable then work perfeclty with sessionSave function in jquery.